# Dynamic hyperlink with mergefield possible?

Tags: url, ms-word, hyperlink, mergefield

I've tried several guides, but i haven't really found that any of them fit my purpose.
The problem seems simple enough, i want to create a dynamic link based on a variable.
I've tried inserting a Hyperlink with temp text and link, replacing the text within the "" brackets, with a MergeField corresponding to the variable.
Whenever i test it, the variable does not register. The syntax is as follows :

{ HYPERLINK "www.staticurl/{MergeField varurl}" }

Does anyone have any suggestions on why this variable does not register?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have not tried this, but, try `{ HYPERLINK "{QUOTE "www.staticurl/{MergeField varurl}"  }" }

Comment: See *Mailmerge Hyperlink ‘Click Here’ Insertion* in the **Mailmerge Tips & Tricks** thread at https://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html